# Iterate named ranges to use with LINEST

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a large data set. I need to filter then copy the filtered data to a new sheet, and perform a polynomial regression to predict data at a certain time.

The length of the data set is not a defined value, and can change from one data set to the next. I use VBA to find the end of the data set, and then I create named ranges that are later used in LINEST.

It works for one filtered data set.

When I iterate through my data, I believe the code overwrites the named ranges with new data. At the end all of my LINEST calculations are the same.

Is there a way to change the named ranges so they can be iterated? I tried creating a variable that was set to my Range name + i, but I can’t use the variable in LINEST.

```
Sub Regression()

Dim TimeX As Range
Dim X_Time As String
Dim Xxx As Range
Dim XX As String
Dim rws As Long

i = 1

Do While i < 70

    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set TimeX = Range("$B$2:$B$" & rws)
    Set Xxx = Range("$C$2:$C$" & rws)

    ‘X_Time = "TimeX" & i
    ‘XX = "Xxx" & i

    X_Time = "TimeX"
    XX = "Xxx"

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=X_Time, RefersTo:=TimeX
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=XX, RefersTo:=Xxx

    Range("L4:N4").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=LINEST(Xxx,TimeX^{1,2},TRUE,FALSE)"

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe change your code like below:

```
' ...
XX = "Xxx" & i
'...
'XX = "Xxx"
Selection.FormulaArray = "=LINEST(" & XX & ",TimeX^{1,2},TRUE,FALSE)"
```